# React native index.js with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am very newbie with React and React native.

I have a folder with several components, I've been able to create an index.js file to export all components inside the folder, so in other components I can do:

````
# /components/OneComponent.js
...
export { OneComponent }

# index.js
import { OneComponent } from './components'
```
````

Now I am working with Redux, and I want to accomplish the same thing, but I don't know how to do it. In my component I export the component as follows:

```
# /component/OneComponent.js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent);
```

And it should be as follows as I guess

```
export { connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent) };
```

But it doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you tried export default connect(mapStateToProps, myFunction)(OneComponent);

Comment: Yes, If I do that, when I do `import { OneComponent } from './components'` it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it out.

You can work around your error by assigning the result of the connect call to a const and then export that const afterward like so.

```
const comp1 = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);

export {comp1 as MyComponent};
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is the Redux, the `import` and `export` ES6 methods are messy. For example:

- Example 1 (with `export default`):

When you export default something, you should not import with {}

```
## CORRECT
# /components/OneComponent.js
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent);

# index.js
import AnyName from './components/OneComponent.js'

## WRONG
# /components/OneComponent.js
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent);

# index.js
import { OneComponent } from './components/OneComponent.js'
```

- Example 2 (without `export default`):

Try to name your object keys

```
##CORRECT
# /components/OneComponent.js
...
export { OneComponent: connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent) };

# index.js
import { OneComponent } from './components'

##WRONG
# /components/OneComponent.js
...
export { connect(mapStateToProps, { myFunction})(OneComponent) };

# index.js
//It wont find the key OneComponent on exported object
import { OneComponent } from './components'
```

Comment: The first example is what I am doing right now. The second example doesn't work for me, I receive an error in the two dots that says ", expected" `export { SchedulesScreen: connect(mapStateToProps, { getSchedules })(SchedulesScreen) };`

Comment: Hi @Robsonsjre , I've created a github repo with the base code, could you check it? Thank you! https://github.com/davidrojo/test-import

Answer (score 0):

When exporting your components from an index you need to export them like this:

`export {connect(mapStateToPops,mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)}`

and then in your index.js:
`export * from 'YourComponentRoute`

Remember that if you export as default you are exporting an instance of an unique object. If you export {} you are exporting a "copy" of an object.

Comment: Hi, if I do this export in the component js file, I get a javascript error at the parenthesis of connect that says ", expected". `export { connect(mapStateToProps, { getSchedules })(SchedulesScreen) };`